# jQuery - calling function with parameters inside method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how is possible to call a function with parameters inside a method.
I have 2 functions and i'd like to call function deleteCode() when clicked on list element which is created by addCode() function.
I'm sure the solution is really simple, but i just can't see it right now. 
Many thanks!

```
function addCode(code) {
    $('#codeList').append('<li class="codeList" onClick="deleteCode(code);">' + code + '</li>');
}

function deleteCode(code) {
    $('#'+code).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it unobtrusive and you're fine.

```
function addCode(code) { 
    $('#codeList').append($('<li>', {
        'class':    'codeList',
        'text':     code,
        'click':    function(e) {
             deleteCode(code);
        }
    }));
}
```

Ref.: [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
function addCode(code) {
    $('<li class="codeList">' + code + '</li>').click(function() {
        deleteCode(code);
    }).appendTo('#codeList');
}

function deleteCode(code) {
    $('#'+code).remove();
}
```

...or more simply:

```
function addCode(code) {
    $('<li class="codeList">' + code + '</li>').click(function() {
        $('#'+code).remove();
    }).appendTo('#codeList');
}
```

When using a library like jQuery (or even when not, frankly), there's virtually never any reason to use the old-style `onclick` attributes for setting up handlers. In the above, I've replaced it with the `click` function, which sets up a handler when the user clicks the element.

**Note**: Lazarus notes that your code is removing an element by `id` using the `code` value:

```
$('#' + code).remove();
```

...but that the code doesn't produce an element with that ID. I assume you've added that element with some other code elsewhere, and that the goal isn't to remove the `li` you've added with this code.

If you *did* want to remove that same `li` on click, no need for an ID at all:

```
function addCode(code) {
    $('<li class="codeList">' + code + '</li>').click(function() {
        $(this).remove(); // <== Changed here
    }).appendTo('#codeList');
}
```

Comment: +1, what I was typing. @jAndy's answer is another great way of doing it. @Downvoter, it's just bad form not to say why you've down voted.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but I might suspect that the lack of a control ID that would cause the example to fail to operate might be the reason for the downvote. You can't `$('#'+code).remove();` if there's no ID set to code to remove.

Comment: @Lazarus: Thanks. That logic just comes from the OP's code. For all we know, he **is** adding an element with that ID which this code is then supposed to remove, and it's just not in the code he quoted. (We don't know that clicking the `li` is supposed to remove *it* -- that can be done rather more directly!) In any case, that would be inappropriately harsh, esp. with no comment.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: The intent seems clear from the sample but accepted that it's probably an equal stretch to either assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `<li>` element via code rather than appending raw HTML.

```
function addCode(code) {
    // Create the <li>
    var newEl = document.createElement("li");
    newEl.className = "codeList";

    // Assign the click function via jquery's event helper.
    $(newEl).click(function(code) {
        // Call your deleteCode function and pass in the given parameter.
        deleteCode(code);
    });

    // Append the new element to the codeList node.
    $(#codeList).append(newEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function addCode(code) {
$('#codeList').append('<li class="codeList" onClick="deleteCode(' + code + ');">'+code+'</li>'); 
}
```